# Trying to use void pointers and random generate an enum array with distinct elements (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, enums, void-pointers

I tried to use void pointers and random generate enum array with no repeated elements. But It still have duplicated elements. Which part of my codes is wrong?

P.S I haven't learnt vectors, shuffle or iota, thus not allow to use it.

This is my enum

```
enum Fruit {Durian, Papaya, Apple, Orange, Mango, Jackfruit, Berry};
```

My main function:

```
int main ()
{
    srand (time (NULL));
    VoidPtr* vpArray;
    int size = rand () % 7;
    vpArray = new VoidPtr [size];
    constructVPArray (vpArray, size); 

}
```

Construct enum and get fruitVP function:

```
VoidPtr getAFruitVP ()
{
   int k = rand () % MAXNO;
   Fruit f = static_cast <Fruit>(k);

   Fruit *fruitPtr;
   fruitPtr = new Fruit;
   *fruitPtr = f;

   VoidPtr vp = fruitPtr;

   return vp;
}

void constructVPArray (VoidPtr *vpArray, int size)
{
    VoidPtr *p = &vpArray [0];      

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *p = getAFruitVP ();

        do
        {
            *p = getAFruitVP ();

        }while (isDuplicate(vpArray, i, *p)); 
        ++p;
    }
}
```

My check for duplicate function

```
bool isDuplicate(VoidPtr *vpArray, int size, VoidPtr p)
{   
    VoidPtr *q = &vpArray [0];          
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        cout << *q << "\t" << p << endl;
        if (*q == p) 
            return true;
        else
            ++q;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why would one use a `void*` pointer to do this? Can you elaborate your rationale about that please. IMO you should at least stick to a `Fruit*` pointer.

Comment: If this is an assignment, please consider just read a good book instead

Comment: @user9212993, oh well, our teacher want us to know how to use void pointer. I know something is wrong with the boolen function, just do not know which part.

Comment: Well, you can't dereference `void*` because there is no type to reference. `if (*q == p) ` desn't make sense.

Comment: @user9212993, yup i just realised, i am not comparing the enum type, instead i am comparing the address

Comment: `MAXNO` seems undefined. Please, read the site guidelines and extract a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Without that, your question is off-topic.